# custom menu icon not being called in onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: java, android

My code as below:-

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    //return true;

    // add this
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.testiv, Menu.NONE, "custom")
        .setActionView(R.layout.test)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    FrameLayout parent = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    VersionChecker version;

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.testiv: 

    //not call  
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I try to call onclick the custom layout icon but fail to go into onOptionsItemSelected.

Answer (score 0):

you set id to your menu but in case don't call that exactly:

```
    aMenuItem add (int groupId, int itemId, int order, int titleRes);
```

you set your item id to 0 but in case statement call `R.id.testiv`, if you want call this you must set id of your menu item to `testiv`

////EDIT

change `groupId` to 0 and use following code:

```
   @Override
   public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.testiv:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }
```

or

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.testiv:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

[more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580111/how-can-i-dynamically-create-menu-items)

Comment: i changed to case 0 but still failed. pls advanced

Comment: change 0 to one another thing and test again, or use R.id.0

Comment: can edit in my post? between i try to debug when onclick is not going in onOptionsItemSelected

Comment: i changed groupId to 0 and itemid to R.id.testiv? and follow your onOptionsItemSelected still failed. not going in this method when debug

Comment: did you try without `setActionView ` and `setShowAsAction`?

Comment: if i disable setShowAsAction can click and show custom as a dropdownbox. But not showing the layout that i'm created for menu