# How to create xml items list programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-xml, android-xmlpullparser

I am using an external API for some actions. One of the method takes a list of menu(xml) items like:

**`----.shape(R.menu.list).---`**

And here is my **`R.menu.list`** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/share"
        android:title="Share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_grey600_18dp"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/upload"
        android:title="Upload"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_green"/>
</menu>
```

The problem is that the items in this **`R.menu.list`** file are not known. They can vary. Say I have a button, on clicking it, I may have 3 items that are needed to be passed to **`.shape()`** method, and sometimes I may have 1 or so items. How can I achieve this.

Comment: check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580111/how-can-i-dynamically-create-menu-items

Answer (score 0):

Prepare different files i.e. R.menu.listShare, R.menu.list.Upload etc

While clicking buttons

i.e. `Share -> call API with R.menu.listShare` and

`Upload -> call API with R.menu.Upload` xml files

This way dynamically you can inflate menu from different menu files

This approach will be `simple to implement and organize actions` according to different buttons