# How to add items in menu dynamically in android

Tags: android, menu

I want to add the menu items dynamically. I have menu like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/allItems"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/trackAll"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/specficItems"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/trackSpecific"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/favItems"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/trackFav"/>

</menu>
```

I try to add items into `favItems`.
But when I try like this :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.admin_menu, menu);

    MenuItem item=menu.findItem(R.id.favItems);

    menu.add(0, MY_MENU_1, 0, "Item 1").setShortcut('3', 'c');
    menu.add(0, MY_MENU_2, 0, "Item 2").setShortcut('4', 's');
    menu.add(0, MY_MENU_3, 0, "Item 3").setShortcut('5', 'z');
    return true;
}
```

The output is coming like this:
[image]

But I want to add this items into `favItems`

Please let me know any idea to add the items dynamically in `favItems`.

If I try like this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {    
    menu.add(0, MY_MENU_1, 0, "Item 1").setShortcut('3', 'c');
    menu.add(0, MY_MENU_2, 0, "Item 2").setShortcut('4', 's');
    menu.add(0, MY_MENU_3, 0, "Item 3").setShortcut('5', 'z');
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

The op coming like this:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580111/how-can-i-dynamically-create-menu-items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are just adding items to the `menu`.

Try doing this:

```
 MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.favItems);
 SubMenu sub = item.getSubMenu();

 sub.add(0, MY_MENU_1, 0, "Item 1").setShortcut('3', 'c');
 sub.add(0, MY_MENU_2, 0, "Item 2").setShortcut('4', 's');
 sub.add(0, MY_MENU_3, 0, "Item 3").setShortcut('5', 'z');
```

Edit:

Also your `favItems` should be something like this:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/favItems"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/trackFav">
    <menu>
    </menu>  
</item>
```

Comment: Yes.. This what I want.. Thank you @ Rane Juuse.. But on this have to add `<menu>        </menu>` this line in menu XML.

Answer (score 0):

use: `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`

> Prepare the Screen's standard options menu to be displayed. This is called right before the menu is shown, every time it is shown. You can use this method to efficiently enable/disable items or otherwise dynamically modify the contents.

```
// Gets called everytime, when menu button is pressed
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear(); //Empty's your menu
    menu.add();  // adding your item

    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    return true;
}
```

**edit:** to add one item because you did something before... you could use:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if(IWantToAddMyItem){
        menu.add(); // your item
        IWantToAddMyItem = false;
    }

    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I have update the question with your solution result. Please refer this and let me, where I did mistake?

Comment: you need to use `menu.clear()` (clears the menu) and than use `menu.add()` to add your desired items