# What does Menu.FIRST mean?

Tags: android

I came across the code here. Can someone explain to what is Menu.First and why +1? I couldn't find it in the Android developer document.

```
    private static final int MENU_ADD = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int MENU_LIST = MENU.FIRST + 1;
    private static final int MENU_REFRESH = MENU.FIRST + 2;
    private static final int MENU_LOGIN = MENU.FIRST + 3;
```

Comment: Where is this code from...? If you look at the source code for [android.view.Menu](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/Menu.java), then you will find `Menu.FIRST`, which  is simply a [constant](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/Defineconstant.htm) value set to `1`. However, the rest of the values (`MENU_LIST` etc...) aren't there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580111/how-can-i-dynamically-create-menu-items from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of [the accepted answer referenced in your comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580111/how-can-i-dynamically-create-menu-items), the poster is simply using these values as id's for dynamically added menu items so that clicks can be registered in `inOptionsItemSelected()`.

For example, say you wanted to add a new button to your `menu` dynamically that turned the screen blue, you might create a constant value called `MENU_TURN_SCREEN_BLUE`. This would store an arbitrary number which you can later use as an id. For example (keeping in mind [`Menu.FIRST = 1`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#FIRST):

```
private static final int MENU_TURN_SCREEN_BLUE = Menu.FIRST + 60;
```

or

```
private static final int MENU_TURN_SCREEN_BLUE = 69084;
```

Are both valid. Now, when you add a new item to a menu with the [`add()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add(int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) method, you can use this value:

```
menu.add(0, TURN_SCREEN_BLUE, 0, "Press To Turn Screen Blue");
```

You could of course just write the number in directly, but constant are helpful (amongst other reasons) for avoiding bugs in your code that arise from accidentally typing in the wrong  number.

Keep in mind though that there are other ways to generate unique id's - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790623/programmatic-views-how-to-set-unique-ids) for details.

Comment: Then will it be possible to set id for such a code  menu.getItem(0).setIcon(R.drawable.bluetooth); on onPrepareOptionsMenu so that I can used it on onOptionsItemSelected()

Comment: @Spotty `getItem()` uses the index (i.e., its position in the menu), to find the item, not the view's `id`, so they aren't the same thing. `menu.findItem(TURN_SCREEN_BLUE).setIcon()` should work though.

Comment: Hi I mean something like this question I just posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637751/how-do-i-set-another-id-for-the-new-icon-i-set-in-onprepareoptionsmenu

Comment: @Spotty That's a very different question to the one you asked. You asked what is `Menu.FIRST` and received two accurate answers. Please accept one of them at least, otherwise you're wasting the time of people who answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/Menu.html)

FIRST Refers to

> First value for group and item identifier integers.

It is a constant value

> Constant Value: 1 (0x00000001)

Refer [this link](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/Menu.html#FIRST)

Comment: :( sorry could you explain what that mean?? I don't quite get it.

Comment: It is basically just a constant with value 1 which can be used for constructing menu groups. Read a very nice overvew of Menus and the usage of such constants here: http://gurushya.com/android-menus-part-1/